# Edit a text in the / public / folder after a build

Tags: build, gatsby

just for info if you want to change a text after the gatsby build, you absolutely need the sources?
Can't we just edit the files in the public folder?

The developer deleted the sources from the project.

it's just a phone to modify,
THX :wink:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the files in the `/public` folder and you'll see the changes "live" or in a production environment, but as soon as you recompile/rebuild your project again, you'll lose those changes, since they aren't applied in the source code (`/src` folder).